Significance of the phase of the condensate as compared to that of the regular Fermi sea in the Anderson-Higgs mechanism
I do not fully understand how the phase of the charged Cooper pair condensate is different from the phase of e.g. the Fermi liquid in a regular metal.
The state of the metal (any quantum state really) should have a phase (and some operator constructed from it which gives non-vanishing expectation value) for which you should be able to make the same argument for the Higgs mechanism in the Ginzburg-Landau formalism as with the condensate phase.
Coherence:
One might argue that maybe the metal is not coherent over macroscopic distances. But neither is the superconductor since it also has a finite coherence length and in the end it should not matter anyway in a local field theory unless superconductivity is actually topological order (which it is also claimed to by e.g. by Xiao Gang Wen). But actually I fail to understand the coherence argument anyway, since ultimately decoherence means that subsystems are entangled with different subsystems of the environment. In the end, a closed system will always be in a pure quantum state (we may not know it and therefore write a mixed state incorporating our uncertainty about the exact state, but this is a matter of description not 'reality' I would say), at least ignoring retardation effects due to relativity. But in the simplistic models one looks at to understand superconductivity there is no environment, so how can the system even be in a mixed state at zero temperature?
SSB:
The Higgs mechanism is usually brought up in connection to SSB and you might argue that the Fermi liquid does not show SSB. But actually, I am not convinced the BCS condensate really does either. At least a BEC condensate does not, although it is regularly claimed to do (see e.g. Tasaki's book). The property that is certainly present is ODLRO, but I have yet to see how one can derive the Higgs mechanism from ODLRO alone with a vanishing order parameter.
As you can see, I also lack some understanding about the meaning of coherence in Quantum mechanics in general. I would be happy about any comments on this, in particular also on potentially wrong assumptions in this line of thought. Thank you!
EDIT:
Let me make my question more precise:
In the BCS condensate, all Cooper pairs share the same state
\begin{equation}
b^\dagger\vert0\rangle = \sum_\textbf{k} \phi_\textbf{k} c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}\uparrow}c^\dagger_{-\textbf{k}\downarrow}\vert0\rangle
\end{equation}
So the total state is given by
\begin{equation}
\vert\Omega_{BCS}\rangle = \left(b^\dagger\right)^{N_{pair}}\vert0\rangle
\end{equation}
which I guess would correspond to the first kind of coherence in Mike Stone's answer. On the other hand, the Fermi liquid is given by
\begin{equation}
\vert \Omega \rangle = \prod_{\vert\textbf{k}\vert<k_F}c^\dagger_{\textbf{k}\uparrow}c^\dagger_{-\textbf{k}\downarrow}\vert 0 \rangle
\end{equation}
where I wrote it in such a way as to show the actual difference compared to the BCS groundstate.
Now these are both pure states of charged particles and in that sense have a coherent phase. Looking at the classical static Ginzburg-Landau model for the SC, the free energy is of the form
\begin{equation}
f = (D\Psi)^\dagger D\Psi + F^2
\end{equation}
where the covariant derivative $D$ and field strength $F$ give the interaction and free part of the gauge field respectively. If $\langle \vert \Psi\vert\rangle \neq 0$ we can derive a mass term for the gauge field and ultimately the Meißner effect from this.
But why does $\Psi$ need to be the wave function of a condensate and not some arbitrary other wavefunction?

The word "coherence" in "coherence length" and in  "quantum coherence" are being used in different senses. In a superconductor the "coherence length" is roughly the size of the cooper pairs and is related to the stiffness of the magnitude of the order parameter. For most practical engineering  purposes one can treat  the phase and magnitude of the superconducting order parameter as being classical despite the fact  that  they  originate from quantum effects.
Again roughly, there is a big difference between a large number $\approx 10^{23}$  of  particles all being in the same  coherent quantum superposition of a pair of microscopic states
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N(\alpha \psi_a(x_i)+  \beta \psi_b(x_i))  
$$
as in a superconducting or Bose condensate, and
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_N) =\alpha \prod_{i=1}^N \psi_a(x_i)+ \beta \prod_{i=1}^N \psi_b(x_i)
$$
as in a Schrodinger cat superposition state of two macroscopic ($N\approx 10^{23}$) systems.  The former is hard to disturb, and effectively classical, while the latter quantum coherence is fragile.
Whe we use very small superconducting devices for quantum computing we are making the second kind of coherence and must treat the phase as a quantum observable, but when using superconducting magnets in MRI machines or accelerators, we are exploiting the first kind of coherence.
The Fermi gas of an ordinary metal does not have either of these types of coherence.

Thank you very much for your response! That clarification on the different meaning of coherence in coherence length was very helpful.

However, I still have some questions regarding your answer besides the unadressed point of SSB and ODLRO.   What do you mean by treating the phase of the order parameter classical? This seems to me doubly impossible. First because it is not even physical due to it being gauge dependent, but even if you gauge fix, is it not associated to a global U(1) phase corresponding to the quantum state? Also, it is not clear to me what $\Psi_{a/b}$ are supposed to be in your explanation of the two types of coherence.

The $\psi_{a/b}$ are just two possibel states. They could be spin for example, then the first case would just be a bunch of aligned spins making an ordinary ferrmomagnet. The direction of magnetization is quite classical. The second case would be a bar-magnet which is in a macroscopic superposition of two possible magnetization directions:    a much more quantum state.   As to your first point, consider a pair of Bose condensates. Their relative order parameter phase is measurable by letting them overlap to produce interference fringes.
